Copy a row from one sheet to another dependent on a dropdown selection and hide on the original sheet
I have an Excel file - with 2 sheets - on the first sheet - with many rows with loads of data - the final row will have a dropdown selection of "None" / "Active" / "Closed" - whenever "Closed" is selected - that entire row should be copied to the next available row on the next sheet and hidden on the initial sheet.
To add to complexity - it is for Excel opened/used within Teams.
Any idea how to go about this?
Many Thanks!!
I tried recording a macro - but this does it for the specific row - i need it for any row chosen.
the code it creates is:
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let selectedSheet = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();
    // Set range S575 on selectedSheet
    selectedSheet.getRange("S575").setValue("Closed");
    let _2024_Closed = workbook.getWorksheet("2024_Closed");
    // Paste to range A521 on _2024_Closed from range A575:S575 on selectedSheet
    _2024_Closed.getRange("A521").copyFrom(selectedSheet.getRange("A575:S575"), ExcelScript.RangeCopyType.all, false, false);
    // Set visibility of row(s) at range 575:575 on selectedSheet to true
    selectedSheet.getRange("575:575").setRowHidden(true);
}

Screenshot of Column S1
Screenshot of error + code

So this is Office Script, not VBA, right? You should set the tags correctly - else you will attract only people with VBA knowledge.

ah apologies - thank you - thats been updated by BigBen - then you very much. Sorry - a newbie to asking questions here :)

the final row will have a dropdown selection - do you mean the final column?

apologies - thats correct - Column S has the 3 selectable drop-down options

Assume the data source is an Excel table (created by Excel Ribbon: Insert > Table or Ctrl+T)
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    const dataSheet = workbook.getWorksheet("Data"); // modify as needed
    // get the source data table
    const table: ExcelScript.Table = workbook.getTable("Table1");
    const dataRange = table.getRange();
    // debug
    console.log(dataRange.getAddress());
    // ***
    const tabFilter = table.getAutoFilter();
    tabFilter.clearCriteria();
    const colHeader = "Status" // modify as needed
    const colIndex = table.getColumnByName(colHeader).getIndex(); // Col S
    // filter Closed
    tabFilter.apply(dataRange,
        colIndex, {
        filterOn: ExcelScript.FilterOn.values, 
        values: ["Closed"]
    });
    const shtClosed = workbook.getWorksheet("2024_Closed");
    const desDataRange = shtClosed.getUsedRange(true);
    const destCell = shtClosed.getCell(desDataRange.getRowCount(),0);
    // copy Closed rows to shtClosed
    destCell.copyFrom(table.getRangeBetweenHeaderAndTotal().getSpecialCells(ExcelScript.SpecialCellType.visible));
    // hidden Closed rows
    table.getColumnByName(colHeader).getFilter().applyCustomFilter("<>*Closed*");
}



Thank you @taller - very much appreciated! - i just tried the code and it says: "Line 5: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getRange')" - how can i overcome this? apologies again - i am a complete newbie with all of this. Thank you very much

Select any cell in the table and create an Excel table by Excel Ribbon: Insert > Table or Ctrl+T.  Microsoft documentation:

Create and format tables


Thank you - i tried that - and the error message now reads "Line 9: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getIndex')". i got no idea what any of this means, its way over me... thank you!

What is the value of cell S1? colHeader = "Status" change the Status to the value of S1.

the status was 'Closed' - i removed it - but still had same error, i changed the code, so the code read 'colHeader = "Closed"' - but still the same error message : Line 9: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getIndex')

No, Closed is one of the possible value in the last col. Variable colHeader should be the value of cell S1. If you can't figure out how to fix it, pls edit your post to share the sample data.

S1 cell value is 'Closed' i set colHeader to Closed. how am i able to share the sample data?

I just added 2 screenshots - hopefully it helps?!

Please add a debug line (as shown in the updated script) to verify the range of the table. It seems that your table may not include column S."

Thank you - i updated the script and i got the follwoing two errors: 1. '2024'!P574:Q577



Line 12: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getIndex') - i think as you stated - it doesnt include column R&S - but not sure where or how to add that in? - Thanks again :)




Im unable to delete the Table - so i tried to create the new table first - then delete, but upon creating the new table - it says 'This will change a filtered range on your worksheet. To complete this task, please remove AutoFilters. - what are autofilters / how can i remove them - so i can create the new table. Thank you

(1). Select any cell in the table, Excel ribbon: Table Design > Convert to Range, delete Table1. (2) select the table range (A1:S10 in my screenshot) (3) press Ctrl+T to create a new table (4) double check the table name, change it to Table1 if needed.

I tried the above steps and keep getting 'This willc hange a filtered range on your worksheet. To complete this task, please remove AutoFilters. the Table1 has been deleted by converting to range.

Then Google it and remove AutoFilters.

Ah fab - i have removed the autofilters - i tried to run the code and i get "Line 12: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getIndex')" - i couldnt remove table1, so i renamed it to 'ignore' and renamed the new table to 'table1' - and i get the error: "'2024'!A1:S10
Line 12: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getIndex')"

According to your screenshot, your table starts from row 2, so it definitely shouldn't be '2024'!A1:S10 (which corresponds to my sample dataset). btw, ExcelScript.Table is same as ListObject in VBA. thespreadsheetguru.com/listobject-tables-vba

Thank you - its all a bit too over my head, i'll try and get some support from MS or somebody. Thank you for your attempts to help a noob like me.
